# How do I make a Memo field sortable?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I have a table with two memo fields. Neither of which I can sort on. The sorting options on the menu is grayed out when I right-click on the column. I have read that it is possible to  sort on memo fields, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it with Advanced Filter/Sort, but it's not very pretty (IMHO).

1. Open your table in Datasheet view
2. On the Home tab in the ribbon Click Advanced in the Sort & Filter group and select Advanced Filter/Sort.
3. In the filter/query designer choose your memo field and select a sort order
4. Click the Toggle Filter button up in the Sort & Filter ribbon group